# Is it possible to export highlighted text with pdf-tools?

Tags: pdf-tools

When using `Skim` I can export any kind of pdf annotations, including highlighted text, to a file.

Is it possible to do the same thing with `pdf-tools` in Emacs?

Comment: I have not tried this but check out this [blog post](http://matt.hackinghistory.ca/2015/11/11/note-taking-with-pdf-tools/) on taking notes with `pdf-tools` and `org-mode`.

Comment: I put the code from the blog post in my init.el and then run `M-x pdf-annot-markups-as-org-text`. It asks for a pdf. I used a pdf with my highlighted annotations but the answer was `wrong type argument`. Nevertheless I think the answer to my question may be in this blog post.

Comment: contains some library process pdf
https://github.com/temberature/pdf2notes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know if it is possible with `pdf-tools`, but it is possible with `org-noter` (https://github.com/weirdNox/org-noter).

Here is a little demonstration:

[image]

You call `org-noter` in the pdf buffer. Then use the `org-noter-create-skeleton` function to exoprt the highlights to the org-noter notes file.

Comment: When I try `org-noter-create-skeleton` I receive the message that this command is only possible with `pdf-tools`.

Comment: @sbac I ran into this too. By default, org-noter will use DocView. You need to take the extra step to package-install pdf tools. https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools

Comment: To be clear it exports things in the hierarchy "Highlight on page N" -> Contents, Comment.  That works fine!  It's too bad that "contents" does not mean the same thing in the `pdf-annot-list-format`... there, `Currently supported properties are page, type, label, date and contents`... but these contents represent the comment!